# Yii Model class column attributes do not match

Tags: activerecord, model, yii

How can Active Record attributes be different than in a model class?
I have a User model in which there is a column from database named dob. I wont be accepting dob as a whole from user hence the rules function won't have anything with dob but instaed, 'date, month,year'

```
 array('date, month, year', 'validDate'),
```

and I am doing this

```
public function afterValidate()
{
parent::afterValidate();
$this->date_of_birth = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->year."".$this->month."".$this->date));
}
```

to have the recorded values in the database. I am not too sure if it's a Active Reocrd thing or Model but the date is stored not what the user enters but 1970-01-01 Unix default, so I am sure to do something wrong.
P.S. I have date month and year as safe in rules.
Code for validDate

```
public function validDate($attributes, $params)
{
   if($this->scenario == 'registration-general')
   {
     if($this->month == 0)
        $this->addError('month','Month cannot be blank');
    elseif(0 > $this->month || $this->month > 12)
        $this->addError('month','Enter a valid month');
   }
}
```

Comment: is there any rule for date_of_birth also? validDate is your own validator? code for that

Comment: Please put the full validation rules

Comment: yes, validDate is my own validation function. There is no rule for date_of_birth. It's just not present in the rules function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you define year, month, and date in the model.

```
public $year;
public $month;
public $date;
```

If these aren't defined, they they aren't being assigned during massive assignment (or any assignment), and your code (as tested on my system) would return 1970-01-01.

Also change your strtotime argument to:

```
$this->year."-".$this->month."-".$this->date
```

With the hyphens you can use 1 or 2 digit month and date format. Without the hyphens you are required to use 2 digits, but noting in your code suggests you guarantee that.

Either of the above issues could be causing your code to fail. Make sure those are fixed, then see if it works.

Edit: The `save()` method calls the `validate()` method unless you pass `false` as a parameter. If year, month, and date are being unset between `validate` and `save`, then the second run of validate will erase the `dob` attribute.

In short, call `save(false)` to save, if you use `validate()` earlier in your script.

Comment: All the three variables are assigned in the model. It stays, i.e value is retained in the next step but disppears in the third step, wherein I call save() on user object.

Comment: The error is then likely someplace else that you are overlooking. Providing more of your code would help. You say your database column is named `dob`, but you are assigning the string to an attribute named `date_of_birth`, could that be the issue?

Comment: typo, sorry, it's dob at both places. But if that was the case, yes, it would have been a problem,in case someone reads this post. Names need to be the same. The code has
        $transaction=Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
which commits the data at step3, my dob has blank value in the 3rd, but correct value in step2. there is data loss since date, month, year are not not considered to be the attributes of User model. I am sure there is something wrong there. What code should I provide, my User model?

Comment: Include anything related to the saving process, so we can see if we can figure out where the issue is. This includes your controller action, plus any relavent parts (`beforeSave`, `save`, `afterSave`, etc) of your User model. Especially include whatever code contains the transaction. Try calling `$user->save(false)` to deactivate validation, if you are already calling `$user->validate()` at some point earlier. IF your year,month,date variables are being emptied somehow, then calling validate a second time (as occurs when calling `save()` without arguments) would erase the `dob` field as well.

Comment: Yes. You got it right, it's calling it the second time. Hence the erasing.

Comment: Excellent. I've added the solution to my answer. Please accept it so others know that your question is answered.